# return only the rows with highest id

Tags: sql

this is what i have:

```
select *
from table
where address1 in ('1235 mary st', '516 fred way', '89 valley st', '5416 apple ave')
order by name
```

the result set returns 100's of records for these 4 addresses (this table is like a purchase table) and this table has an ID# for each row but i only want to pull the row with the highest ID#. Hope this is enough info.

I would think just use max(table ID#) but with the IN clause its pulling only the highest table ID for all 4 of these addresses.  i only want the most recent

Comment: `order by id desc` And then take the first entry with whatever DB engine you use. For MySQL it is `limit 1`, for MSSQL `top 1`

Comment: Do you need to have exactly one row for each address?

Answer (score 1):

On databases that support windowing functions, you can use `row_number()` to assign increasing numbers per address:

```
select  *
from    ( 
        select  row_number() over (partition by address1
                                   order by id desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    table
        where   address1 in (...)
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Only latest row per address
```

Comment: SELECT distinct *
FROM cust AS C
WHERE  internalid IN (
SELECT DISTINCT customerid 
FROM purch as p
WHERE ADDRESS1 IS NOT NULL 
AND ADDRESS1 IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT ADDRESS1 
FROM Address AS A
WHERE  customerid not in 
(SELECT distinct customerid
FROM Customer AS C
WHERE C.CUSTOMERID=A.CUSTOMERID))).... when i take the address1 and compare it to the purch table, thats when i get tons of extra records, when in fact i just want to trace the stray records from the bottom subquery back to the purch table

Answer (score 0):

What *I think* you want is the most recent purchase for each address.  If that's right, something like this might do the trick:

```
select top 1 *
from table
where address1 = '1235 mary st'
order by id desc

UNION ALL

select top 1 *
from table
where address1 = '516 fred way'
order by id desc

UNION ALL

select top 1 *
from table
where address1 = '89 valley st'
order by id desc

UNION ALL

select top 1 *
from table
where address1 = '5416 apple ave'
order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand the question correctly. This query will return 1 row for each address and the max id for that address.

```
select max(id), address1
from table
where address1 in ('1235 mary st', '516 fred way', '89 valley st', '5416 apple ave')
group by address1
```

Comment: Sorry my orig post was a lil test query that im using.. I have a larger query with several subqueries inside. im trying to trace the stray records between 2 tables back to a history table via the address1 column, but when i do so im getting all the transactions tied to that address1, which i dont want. i only want most recent which i thought i could pull by the ID in that history table. sorry for my messed up post. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxId, address1
FROM table
WHERE address1 in ('1235 mary st', '516 fred way', '89 valley st', '5416 apple ave')
GROUP BY address1
```